# How to make a textfield to enter only characters and spaces in iphone sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

Need a suggestion for How to make the textfield to enter only text and spaces.

Comment: http://hugolarcher.com/uitextfield-allowing-only-decimal-characters/ a simple tutorial to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out the following code snippet:

`myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcABC"];`

`

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range      replacementString:(NSString *)string {

for (int i = 0; i < [textEntered length]; i++) {

    unichar c = [textEntered characterAtIndex:i];
    if (![myCharSet characterIsMember:c]) {
        return NO;
    }
}
return YES;}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code,

`UITextField` has delegate method name is

`– textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` This is help in your case.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if(textField == yourTextFieldName)
    {
        NSCharacterSet *invalidCharSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"] invertedSet]; invertedSet];
        NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:invalidCharSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        if([string isEqualToString:filtered] || [string isEqualToString:@" "])
        return YES;
    }
    else
        return NO;
}
```